# Prevent default click event action of Vuetify tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I'm using Vuetify tab for showing some forms, I want to add a button as the last element in tab which helps to create a new tab. Now I can prevent the event bubbling to tab by using `@click.stop` but whenever clicked outside the button(within the `v-tab`) it triggering tab change event, I tried `@click.prevent` and `@change` to prevent the default action but nothing seems working. Even I tried `disabled` property but it disabling the entire tab including the button.

```
<v-tab @click.stop.prevent="addNew">
  <v-btn class="d-flex" @click.prevent.stop="addNew">Add new</v-btn>
</v-tab>
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/pranavcbalan/pen/BaBXpdM)

Comment: Why make it a tab? You seem to be trying to make a "tab" not behave like a tab. You can make a `v-layout` with the tabs and then place the button _outside_ of the tabs.

Comment: @Michael let me try

Comment: @Michael :  another workaround - https://codepen.io/pranavcbalan/pen/YzKmZzd

Comment: @Michael :  thanks man, https://codepen.io/pranavcbalan/pen/LYPwWEB